# Boundedness on k-tuple euclidean space

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

I am currently studying, "Elementary Analysis:The Theory of Calculus" by Kenneth A. Ross, in my edition on page 82, bounded sequences in $\Re^k$, k-tuple Euclidean space is defined as follow:

A set S in $\Re^k$ is bounded if there exists $M>0$ such that $\max(\left |x_j \right |:j=1,2,...,k)\leqslant M  $ for all $x\in S$.

What I want to ask is that, should not this bound be defined accordingly to the metric on the space, that is;

A set S in $\Re^k$ is bounded if there exists $M>0$ such that $d(x,0)\leqslant M$ for all $x\in S$. I think,this intuition of mine is based on my perspective on the definiton of a bounded set on $\Re$, I see it as, S is bounded if there exist an M such that, the magnitude of M (that is $d(M,0)=\left |M-0 \right |$,the usual metric on $\Re$) is greater than the magnitudes of all elements of the set. Hence this notion of taking the elements $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_k)$ from $\Re^k$, and examining the magnitude (metric on $\Re$) of each coordinate of x seperately and bounding them instead of calculating $d(x,0)$ and bounding this comes not natural.

Would you share your ideas on this with me? Why boundedness is defined in such a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right - but, as it turns out, the two notions are equivalent.

There are lots of ways to define a metric on $\Bbb R^k$. The "natural" Euclidean metric is $d(x,y) = \|x-y\|_2$, where $\|z\|_2 = \sqrt{z_1^2+\cdots+z_k^2}$. Another way is to set $d'(x,y) = \|x-y\|_\infty$, where $\|z\|_\infty = \max\{|z_1|,\dots,|z_k|\}$. (And there are many others besides, such as the metrics induced by the $p$-norms for all $p\ge1$.)

These metrics give different values for the distance from $x$ to $y$. But they are all (strongly) *[equivalent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics#Strong_equivalence)* metrics: they differ by at most a constant factor, so that there exist positive constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $\alpha d(x,y) \le d'(x,y) \le \beta d(x,y)$. (In this case, one can take $\alpha=1$ and $\beta=\sqrt k$.) Equivalent metrics give the same answers to lots of questions (they induce the same topology, for example). In particular, a set is bounded under the $d$ metric if and only if it is bounded under the $d'$ metric.

By the way, I would say it's even more natural to say that a set $S$ is bounded if and only if there exists $M'$ such that $d(s,t) \le M'$ for all $s,t\in S$. This definition doesn't require singling out a special point like the origin that might have nothing to do with $S$ anyway. Note that the two notions are still equivalent, thanks to the triangle inequality $d(s,t) \le d(s,0) + d(t,0)$.

Comment: Thanks very much, now I understand it. And the latter part where you point out the fact that I should not single out a special point is mostly satisfying(that was another question on my mind.) @Greg Martin